# How to get notified when Flash is ON or OFF in Auto flash mode due to low light

Tags: ios, swift, flash, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Am using UIImagePickerController to present the camera and initially make the flash mode to Auto.

```
videoCapturer.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
videoCapturer.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
videoCapturer.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.Auto
[self .presentViewController(videoCapturer, animated: true, completion: nil)]
```

[image: i see a yellow flash icon appear and disappear according to the lighting in the bottom upper to the capture button.]

i want to get notified when the flash is set to ON or off according to the lighting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use KVO.

```
let capture = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
capture.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "torchActive", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New.union(.Initial), context: nil)
```

And implement this method:

```
public override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "torchActive" {
        // do something when torchActive changed
    } else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Here is Apple's description of torchActive:

```
 @property torchActive
 @abstract
     Indicates whether the receiver's torch is currently active.

 @discussion
     The value of this property is a BOOL indicating whether the receiver's torch is 
     currently active. If the current torchMode is AVCaptureTorchModeAuto and isTorchActive
     is YES, the torch will illuminate once a recording starts (see AVCaptureOutput.h 
     -startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:). This property is key-value observable.
```

Comment: This is called only when UIImagePickerController class is presented , not called when the flash mode is changed automatically due to lighting .